# how to check if object.values in array are the same in sequence

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, sorting

I have a case in my react app in which I have to check if values of object in array are the same in sequence and their other property increases squentialy by 1, and then if criteria is fulfilled push it to the new array. Number of values in sequence is provided from input.

For example user wants to push 4 objects to a new array that have their `"status": true`

```
objects =  [
{
"someID": 0,
"status": false,
},
{
"someID": 1,
"status": false,
},
{
"someID": 2,
"status": true,
},
{
"someID": 3,
"status": true,
},
{
"someID": 4,
"status": true,
},
{
"someID": 6,
"status": true,
},
{
"someID": 7,
"status": false,
},
{
"someID": 8,
"status": false,
},
{
"someID": 9,
"status": true,
},
{
"someID": 10,
"status": true,
},
{
"someID": 11,
"status": true,
},
{
"someID": 12,
"status": true,
},

]
```

from my example objects with someID 2, 3, 4, 6, fulfill the criteria to have `status: true` but their `someID` values do not increase sequentially by 1 on the other hand those objects with `someID` 9, 10, 11, 12 have their `status` value as true and their `someID` values increase sequentially by 1. So the outcome should be

```
newArray = [
{
"someID": 9,
"status": true,
},
{
"someID": 10,
"status": true,
},
{
"someID": 11,
"status": true,
},
{
"someID": 12,
"status": true,
},
]
```

Comment: what should be the output here?

Comment: an array with objects that fulfill the requirement, for the example I provided it would be newArray = [ {"someID": 2,"status": true,}, {"someID": 3,"status": true,}, {"someID": 4,"status": true,}, ]

Comment: what outcome is expected for cases like 2 times in sequence? you have [2,3] and [3,4] that fullfill the condition, how would be the outcome? You want the first sequence only as return when you have multiple matches? and is it based on a specific object property only or should it match the property and all others props (besides someID) should match?

Comment: with multiple matches first encountered is enough, in fact I have wrongly asked and now I see it, case is that object pushed to the new array need to have the same status property and their `someID` property value have to increase sequentially, ie we need 4 (still value comes from user, can be 4 but can be 3 or 1 or 5) objects in sequence with `"status": true` and their `"someID"` to be sequential like [0,1,2,3] or [3,4,5,6] but cant be [3,4,6,7] even when their status is true in sequence  @buzatto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

below a generic function that takes your array and iterates through a for loop. you pass down the property and expected matched value, just like the exact count in sequence expected:

```
const getSequence = (arr, count, key = 'status', value = true, id = 'someID') => {
  let match = []
  const isIDIncremental = (obj) => {
    if(match.length === 0) return true
    return obj[id] - 1 === match[match.length - 1][id]
  }

  for(const obj of arr) {
    if(match.length === count) break
    if(obj[key] === value && isIDIncremental(obj)) {
      match.push(obj)
    } else {
      match = []
    }
  }
  
  return match.length === count ? match : []
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check `status` and the predecessor or successor.

```js
const
    objects = [{ someID: 0, status: true }, { someID: 1, status: false }, { someID: 2, status: true }, { someID: 3, status: true }, { someID: 4, status: true }, { someID: 5, status: false }, { someID: 6, status: false }, { someID: 7, status: true }],
    result = objects.filter(({ someID, status }, i, a) => status && (
        a[i - 1]?.status && a[i - 1]?.someID === someID - 1 ||
        a[i + 1]?.status && someID + 1 === a[i + 1]?.someID
    ));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: If I'm not mistake this works only in case when i need 3 times  `true`, but will it work when I want 4  or 5 objects in sequence to be `true`?, number of objects with `"status": true` in sequence is provided from `input`. I'm still inexperience could you tell me what `?` does in  this situation `a[i - 1]?.status` ?

Comment: you need only two items in sequence. fyi: [optional chaining operator `?.`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)